# What happened to my game data?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

In 2014, I bought Far Cry: The Wild Expedition (Whole collection from Classic to Blood Dragon) from a local video game store. I opened the box to find Far Cry 2&3 on disc while the other 2 were digital versions with provided Download Codes.

Now since I've never had Internet connection at home, I never downloaded them. But when a friend got connection, I gave him a 16 GB Flashdrive and the DL codes. He used it as a storage device for a while (seeing as he got a 4 GB console) for his games before finally giving it back to me, claiming to have loaded my games on. Now when I tried to install them, the console said it was royally empty. Different from my PC that shows it's totally full but it still has no item in it.

So can anybody please shed some light on what is going on?

Comment: Your friend apparently deleted everything off the USB, or its defective.

Comment: Google your USB problem ('USB full not showing files' something like that). There are a few commands you could run in cmd on your pc to check if the USB is actually defective or just empty.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Nolonar commented on your [duplicate question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301203/redeem-game-codes). If your friend redeemed the codes for any DLC or any game, with his account, you essentially gifted him this particular game/DLC. You can't redeem it again, you have to buy it once more. But if he used your account to redeem the codes than you can download it again.

Also I am fairly sure that you can't download a game/DLC on one Xbox with one account and just transfer it to another Xbox with another account, that would break there business model. But i might be wrong about that.